# How to get a partial view Html in the controller inside a folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a partial view named `Form.cshtml` in `Shared` folder. There is not any action and controller for it. It is in `Shared` folder and I just render it in a view named `Index` in `Home` controller.

All of codes I found needed a controller context but I do not have any controllers. So can I get the Html by the view physical address or any other way?

Comment: There might be more ways, but one way of doing that might be [Razor Generator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you but can you please add some more details to show a more highlighted way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Controller You must do like this

```
   public ActionResult GetPartial()
    {
      var viewStr=RenderRazorViewToString("~/Views/Home/Partial1.cshtml",new object())
      return content(viewStr);
    }

    // by this method you can  get string of view -- Update
    public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
        {
            ViewData.Model = model;
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                                         viewName);
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                             ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
```

Comment: This will return a partial view.I need a method in the controller that return a string containing the html of a partial view inside shared folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759898/4104866  you can use this to render any partial to string,a i think any controller context will be work ,because of using full path to view

Comment: @HamidReza if you have an ajax request and your content type is html this code return you partial view html

Comment: @M.Azad I am seeing this error: Type 'ASP._Page_Views_Shared_Form_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'.

Comment: @HamidReza you call your action with ajax request?

Comment: No. After posting a form I want to get html content of the submitted form(that is placed in a partial view) in the controller.

Comment: @HamidReza I Update my answer and its worked for me...chek it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62870/discussion-between-hamid-reza-and-m-azad).

Answer (score 3):

all you need to specify full path to view

#### Home/Index.cshtml

```
@Html.Partial("/Views/Shared/Form.cshtml")
```

### Edit

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759898/4104866 you can use this to render any partial to string,a i think any controller context will be work ,because of using full path to view

Comment: I update the question title. I want to get the html it in the controller.

Comment: In Controller Must add ~ in View address "~/Views/..."

Comment: Kostina I tried three type of callings:
RenderRazorViewToString("~/Views/Shared/Form.cshtml")=>SearchedLocations is null.
RenderRazorViewToString("Form")=>SearchedLocation is null.
RenderRazorViewToString("Form.cshtml")=>SearchedLocations(~/Views/Shared/Form.cshtml.cshtml,~/Views/Shared/Form.cshtml.vbhtml)

Comment: RenderRazorViewToString("/Views/Shared/Form.cshtml") did you try this? without `~`

Comment: @KostiaMololkin SearchedLocation is null again and returning string is "".

Comment: this.RenderPartialViewToString("//Views//Shared//Form.cshtml", null) trying this and its work for me